# Android Cordova Plugin locks UI thread even though Thread Pool is used

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've written a Cordova plugin that does image re-sizing of images on Android, but the UI locks while thumbing a large number of images (over 100) until the thumbing stops.  I'm performing all of the resizing on the theadPool, initially with just a runnable, but after reading this blog post on [Cordova Plugins and Thread Blocking](http://red-folder.blogspot.ca/2014/05/cordova-plugins-and-thread-blocking.html) I switched to an external class to do the work.   However I am still getting:

```
W/PluginManager﹕ THREAD WARNING: exec() call to ImageStore.getImage blocked the main thread for 91ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
```

For every image resized, the call looks like this:

```
private boolean getImage(final JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

    JSONObject argObject = args.getJSONObject(0);

    int photoId = argObject.getInt("photoId");
    final PhotoData photoData = mPhotos.get(photoId);

    cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new GetImageRunnable(photoData, callbackContext));

    return true;
}
```

Where GetImageRunnable has no links to the main plugin except the photoData object that is passed in.  Is there any way to see what is causing the slowdown or blocking the main the thread?

Comment: I would try using an AsyncTask and ignoring CordovaInterface's seemingly buggy functionality. (Others seem to have this problem too).

Comment: @vbence add this as an answer, and if possible provide some kind of example and I will mark it as accepted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the following code a try, it uses a minimal [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to run the `GetImageRunnable`:

```
private boolean getImage(final JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

    JSONObject argObject = args.getJSONObject(0);

    int photoId = argObject.getInt("photoId");
    final PhotoData photoData = mPhotos.get(photoId);

    (new MyTask(photoData, callbackContext)).execute();

    return true;
}

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private PhotoData mPhotoData;
    private CallbackContext mCallbackContext;

    public MyTask(PhotoData photoData, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        mPhotoData = photoData
        mCallbackContext = callbackContext;
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... v) {
        (new GetImageRunnable(photoData, callbackContext)).run();
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... v) {
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
    }
}
```

It leaves something to be desired though; the callback will be run in the background thread. If you need it to be run in the main thread, you can mask the initial `CallbackContext` (it is not final), and pass the result to the original one in the `onPostExecute`:

```
private boolean getImage(final JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

    JSONObject argObject = args.getJSONObject(0);

    int photoId = argObject.getInt("photoId");
    final PhotoData photoData = mPhotos.get(photoId);

    (new MyTask(photoData, callbackContext)).execute();

    return true;
}

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private PhotoData mPhotoData;
    private CallbackContext mCallbackContext;
    private CallbackContext mMaskedContext;

    public MyTask(PhotoData photoData, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        mPhotoData = photoData
        mCallbackContext = callbackContext;
        mMaskedContext = new MyCallbackContext(callbackContext);
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... v) {
        (new GetImageRunnable(photoData, mMaskedContext)).run();
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... v) {
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
        mCallbackContext.sendPluginResult(mMaskedContext.getPluginResult());
    }
}

class MyCallbackContext extends CallbackContext {
    private CallbackContext mOriginalContext;
    private PluginResult mPluginResult;

    public MyCallbackContext(CallbackContext originalContext) {
        super(originalContext.getCallbackId(), null);
        mOriginalContext = originalContext;
    }

    public void sendPluginResult(PluginResult pluginResult) {
        mPluginResult = pluginResult;
    }

    public pluginResult getPluginResult() {
        return mPluginResult;
    }
}
```

*Note: This is not tested, the code is there just to illustrate the ideas.*